# jQuery Ajax GET with quotes gives MySQL syntax error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, syntax-error

I'm sending a AJAX Call to a seperate file for a MySQL INSERT query. Everything works perfect until someone uses a quote ('); MySQL throws a syntax error even though before the query I use addslashes and mysqli_real_escape_string. This problem occurs in Safari but doesn't in Chrome.

Anyone know more about this specific issue and how to fix it?

**jQuery Ajax**

```
 $('body').on('keyup', '.dbDriven', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({url: 'dbUpdate.inc.php',type: "GET",data:
            {
                val: val
            }
        }).done(function ( data ) {
                        console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

**dbUpdate.inc.php**

```
$_GET['val'] = addslashes($_GET['val']);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['val']);

mysqli_query("UPDATE table SET column = `".$value."` WHERE id = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should consider learning about SQL injection. Data should not be going to the DB raw :/

Comment: `addslashes` is really not the right tool for the job, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is suboptimal and it sounds like you aren't using it correctly.

Comment: Read about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) and how to use a modern API to[defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) against them.

Comment: For the record, if you don't show the specific code that you're using, you're unlikely to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is more easily pass the variable through the url, this work only with "GET" method

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.dbDriven', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({url: 'dbUpdate.inc.php?val='+val,type: "GET"

    }).done(function ( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

never use " " in javascript, it is a bad practice  if you want you can directly make the POST or GET call like this :

```
      $.post(URL,data,callback);
```

or

```
      $.get(URL,data,callback);
```

or with you way :

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'yoururl',
            type:'POST',           
            success: function(){                
        }});
```

Regards

Answer (score -4):

Use this code to prevent SQLi:

```
$str = stripslashes(strip_tags(@trim(str_replace("'", "", $str))));
```

Comment: So you're not going to allow your users to use single-quotes? Umm… no.  That's not the way to do it.

Comment: Then he can use it like this: `$str = stripslashes(strip_tags(@trim("'")));`

Comment: What u suggest then ?